# Why my signal handler executes twice?

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, kill

I am learning inter-process communication in Linux, using kill() to send signals to sleeping child process.Here is my program:

```
 8 void func(void);
 9 int main(void){
 10         int i, j;
 11         pid_t status, retpid;
 12         signal(17,func);
 13         if( i = fork() ){
 14                 printf("Parent:signal 17 will be sent to child!\n");
 15                 kill(i, 17);
 16                 wait(0);
 17                 printf("child process terminated\n");
 18                 }
 19         else{   
 20                 sleep(10);
 21                 printf("Child: A signal from my parent is received!\n");
 22                 exit(0);
 23         }
 24 }
 25 void func(void) 
 26 {
 27         printf("the signal has been sent!\n");
 28 }
```

Compiled with gcc,the program produced abnormal result,in which func() executed twice:

```
./test4.out
Parent:signal 17 will be sent to child!
the signal has been sent!
Child: A signal from my parent is received!
the signal has been sent!
child process terminated
```

I analyzed the result and then deleted the following two line:

```
 16                 wait(0);
 17                 printf("child process terminated\n");
```

And the result became normal,with func() called only once. It seems that the culprit is wait() function,but why would it ever call a signal handler?

Comment: **Maybe** when the parent process is closing down it's waiting for a KILL signal from the process reaper...? After a process is finished, it doesn't really die. It stays until the "raper" (either the owner or the system process in charge of reaping zombie processes) is finished... It could be the reaper signaling that it's done.

Comment: `printf` is not a signal safe function and should not be called in a signal handler. The possible explanation is that it's causing Undefined Behaviour (e.g. flushing the stout buffer twice - once in the signal handler and once when the process exits).

Comment: please post text code, not with prepended line numbers.  We cannot just grab the posted code and paste it into our editors without also having to do lots of line by line editing.  Do not use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for individual preferences.  Even after fixing the line number problem, the posted code does not compile.  It seems to be missing the needed `#include` statements

Comment: the function: `fork()` returns 3 separate return values.  -1 == error, 0 == child >0 == parent.   The posted code fails to handle the error case

Comment: this is the prototype for a signal handler: `void <signal handler func name> (int sig)`,  which is NOT what the posted code is using

Comment: there is a long list of functions that are 'ok' to use inside a signal handler, `printf()` is NOT one of them.  Suggest reading the man page for signal(7)

Comment: in linux, the function: `signal()`  is considered unreliable and not consistently implemented.  the man page for `signal(2)`  strongly suggest to use: `sigaction()` instead.

Comment: this line: `printf("Child: A signal from my parent is received!\n");` is not necessarily true.   suggest removing (or rewording) that line

Comment: Every time a child status change, the parent is informed via `SIGCHLD` signal. `wait()` causes parent to wait until child has completed. When this child finished, the parent then received this `SIGCHLD` from os and the handler is again called. Your workaround, didn't fix the issue. You terminated the parent long before the child is done.

Comment: @user3629249 thank you so much for your patience , I've corrected my code on your suggestion on my computer, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending signal 17 to the child process, so its handler is invoked as expected.

Signal 17 is `SIGCHLD`. `SIGCHLD` is sent to a parent process when a child process dies. The parent's handler is being called when the child exits. This signal isn't coming from the parent; it's coming from the OS, to notify the parent of the child's death.

Answer (score 0):

after correcting (most) of the errors in the posted code..

The result is the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void func( int );

int main(void)
{
    pid_t i;
    //pid_t status;
    //pid_t retpid;
    signal(17,func);


    if( (i = fork()) )
    {
        printf( "the fork'd child pid:%d\n", i );
        printf("Parent:signal 17 will be sent to child!\n");
        kill(i, 17);
        wait(NULL);
        printf("child process terminated\n");
    }

    else
    {   
        sleep(10);
        printf("Child: pid:%d\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
}

void func( int theSignal) 
{
    if( 17 == theSignal )
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "the 17 signal has been processed by %d!\n", getpid());
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "the %d signal is processed\n", theSignal );
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
the fork'd child pid:4845
Parent:signal 17 will be sent to child!
the 17 signal has been processed by 4845!
Child: pid:4845
the 17 signal has been processed by 4844!
child process terminated
```

Which clearly shows that both the parent and the child process the signal

EDIT:

However when a unique SIGUSR2 value is used as in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void func( int );

#define MY_SIGNAL (31)

int main(void)
{
    pid_t i;
    //pid_t status;
    //pid_t retpid;
    signal(17,func);
    signal(31,func);

    if( (i = fork()) )
    {
        printf( "the fork'd child pid:%d\n", i );
        printf("Parent:signal %d will be sent to child!\n", MY_SIGNAL);
        kill(i, MY_SIGNAL);
        wait(NULL);
        printf("child process terminated\n");
    }

    else
    {   
        sleep(10);
        printf("Child: pid:%d\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
}

void func( int theSignal) 
{
    if( MY_SIGNAL == theSignal )
    {
        printf("the %d signal has been processed by %d!\n", MY_SIGNAL, getpid());
    }

    else
    {
        printf( "the %d signal is processed\n", theSignal );
    }
}
```

then the output is:

```
the fork'd child pid:5099
Parent:signal 31 will be sent to child!
the 31 signal has been processed by 5099!
Child: pid:5099
the 17 signal is processed
child process terminated
```

which clearly shows the child processed signal 31 (SIGUSR2) and the parent processed signal 17 (SIGCHLD)

Comment: This still has the error of calling a non-signal-safe function from a signal handler.

Comment: I did say that I corrected "MOST" of the errors in the posted code.  The purpose of my answer was not to instruct/demonstrate how to write a signal handler, but rather to show why the signal handler is executed more than once

Comment: NOTE: the reason the parent gets a signal is that SIGCHLD also has a value of 17 which means that value is not unique.  If the OP were to use 31, for SIGUSER2, Then it would be unique.  I have edited the answer to show this relationship